# qml- Unable to assign DragHandler to a parent window, window overlaps taskbar when maximizing

Tags: qml

I have a frameless qml window with a custom window decoration I created. And I am trying to assign a DragHandler to the window decoration with the target being the window. But I a specific error and only the custom window decoration is being dragged inside the window, the rest of the window remains as it is (not being dragged).

Also this window decoration contains the maximize button which I defined myself, it perfectly works, however the taskbar cannot be accessed while the window is maximized.

[image: This is how the application looks at the moment.]

Can anyone help me see what is going wrong here and fix this?

Here is the error I received

`file:///D:/QML tutorial/Tutorial_UI/Tutorial_UI.qml:92:21: Unable to assign Tutorial_UI_QMLTYPE_11 to QQuickItem`

And here is my code (window and the titlebar)

```
Window {

    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("QNotepad")

    property int previousX
    property int previousY

    color: "#272727"
    
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    TitleBar {
        id: title_bar

        color: (window.active) ? "#1A212B" : "#272727"

        width: 645
        height: 50

        //draggable widget

        DragHandler{
            id: draghandler

            target: window
        }


        Text {
            id: titlebar_text
            text: "QNotePad"

            color: "white"

            x: 20
            y: 10
        }

    }
```

And my code for the maximize button

````
ToolbarButton {
                id: max_btn

                text: ""

                text_color: "white"

                onClicked: {

                    window.visibility === Window.Maximized ? (window.showNormal(), max_btn.text = "", title_bar.width = 645, title_bar.height = 50, tool_bar.width = 640, tool_bar.height = 50, close_btn.x = 595, max_btn.x = 545, min_btn.x = 505, view.height = 600, view.width = container.width) : (window.showMaximized(), max_btn.text = "" , title_bar.width = Screen.width,  tool_bar.width = Screen.width, close_btn.x = (Screen.width-45), max_btn.x = (Screen.width-95), min_btn.x = (Screen.width-135), view.height = (Screen.height-40), view.width = Screen.width)

                }

                x: 545
                y: 0

    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `DragHandler`, consider using `MouseArea` with `drag.target` set. e.g.

```
TitleBar {
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: window
    }
}
```

Here's an example of `MouseArea` with `drag.target` working in a mock application:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#8ac" }
    NotePadApp {
        id: app1
        x: 200
        y: 200
    }

    NotePadApp {
        id: app2
        x: 400
        y: 100
    }
}

// NotePadApp.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: page
    width: 400
    height: 400
    header: TitleBar {
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: page
        }
    }

    Frame {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}

// TitleBar.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    width: parent.width
    height: titleText.height + 20
    color: "#888"
    property string title: "QNotePad"
    Text {
        id: titleText
        x: 10
        y: 10
        text: title
        color: "white"
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADJ3iclVLBboMwDL3zFRE7TqKl2gH11k3abVOZ+gMeeCFqIJkxaqup/74ABQLStM235zw/2y9WpTXEIuW0UdkxUDMYPZmKyeg62INE8RUIF++QHSWZpsq34g0zhkpq9yYyow1tRXiXQBaKa8d9NYx7yHfW3orbUK4QrI3HxHkrNuv1CC8TvAa/ymx8mYe5TDzKOKHVytOJPku9WPYvu7c9rYMdOKmci6lngUoW7GPI0RlyUKzxEcgb/cU0Ne4Iwcu1AVVWGKqjD6V124iw4hkhJ5ARA0lkb5B+Rc+vZ4ISPe0fdQdjhhn/Y4v3974dvXrUoZkv3PY44JmjPiPu3Td3jOlykiTsMpaMReKLqJlUJftax0hvP9izWrHFQYxN/KuIF0cxInbEW82YG4Y5FYoxHFz6Bit433s=)

Comment: before using DragHandler I had exactly that but got the same error. Then I switched to DragHandler.

Edit 1: Tried it again, still get the same error